# Prerequisites for differential geometry.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question, self-learning

Next semester we will be going to study differential geometry. I want to know what prerequisites do I need from geometry(maybe analytic too) to understand most from it? I saw this type of questions but no question contained prerequisite knowledge from geometry.I studied geometry at high school and most of it never used for analysis,algebra,topology and forgot most of it. Will be glad if you can say what I need from geometry so I can relearn it and be ready for differential one.Thank you.

Comment: No, geometry is not needed. All you need is analysis, linear algebra and multivariable-calculus, and may be a little bit of topology.

Comment: The right person to ask is your instructor: There are multiple ways to come into the subject. (That said, your textbook should give some indication of prerequisites.)

Comment: We assume this is an undergraduate differential geometry class. But even with that assumption, it's hard to answer your question without knowing your university's prerequisites, the text, and your instructor's approach to the subject. But, yes, differential geometry has very little to do with high school Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Arctic Char A certain understanding/practise of 3D geometry is also needed at least when you deal with surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with geodesics, etc.